# How to print text to an existing pdf file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I have created new PDFs many times using Zend and PHP. But Now I have a patient form in PDF format and I have to fill that form using my application. How can I print text on existing PDF file with already have some text. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done it, but it certainly seems possible.  See [Zend_Pdf::load()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.create.html), for example.  It seems like you ought to be able to load the PDF, manipulate it, and save then save it somewhere.

Last time I had to do this, Zend_Pdf wasn't around, and I ended up using [fpdf/fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/), which was ugly but worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Does the PDF contain form fields ?  If so you can use FDF type functions.

See [Filling PDF Forms with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php)  - there should be a solution in there somewhere.