# Writing/Drawing over a PDF template document in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'd like to be able to write/overlay text over an existing pdf document using PHP. What I am hoping to do is have a pdf document that can act as a template, and fill in the gaps by opening the template doc, overlaying the relevant text, and serving the result as a new document. The template document is a single page so page merging/manipulation is not necessary.

Are there any free libraries that can do this? Anywhere I should look? Most searches I've done seem to deal with merging documents/adding pages, instead of overlaying content over an existing page.

Thanks.

*EDIT:
Here is what I did:
1. Download FPDF
2. Download FPDI + FPDF_TPL from

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/

Here is some sample code for any future wanderers (adapted from the samples at www.setasign.de):

```
<?php 
include('fpdf.php'); 
include('fpdi.php'); 

// initiate FPDI 
$pdf =& new FPDI(); 
// add a page 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
// set the sourcefile 
$pdf->setSourceFile('templatedoc.pdf'); 
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
// use the imported page as the template 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0); 

// now write some text above the imported page 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial'); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0); 
$pdf->SetXY(25, 25); 
$pdf->Write(0, "This is just a simple text"); 

$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D'); 
?>
```

Comment: Glad you edited in an example of the answer, +1 for that, easy isn't it? :-)

Comment: Yes! And it will help me too when in a few weeks I forget what I've done and look for it again :P (Haven't implemented it yet for my project, just found out how to).

Comment: did you find any way to append image in existing document instead of writing text?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at the [FPDI Library](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) an add on to [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) for template annotation.

It can also bolt-on to [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf), another popular PHP PDF library.  An existing PDF is used as the base of a page, instead of a blank, after that the procedures are the same as regular PDF creation.

Comment: Thanks! Nice and easy to overlay text through code as I want to.

Comment: If you just want to fill out a form, do consider the FDF route discussed by moontear, as it is preferable to annotation.  If you need to make more substantial changes, then FPDI on TCPDF is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use PDF Forms for what you want to do. To fill these babies you could use the FDF method described here: [Using HTML forms to fill in PDF fields with PHP and FDF](http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/).
There is actually another nice SO post about PDF form filling here: [Filling PDF Forms with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php).

Comment: +1 Because FDF is the best method for form modification if you do not need to make annotations that forms can not cater for.

Comment: +1 This is an elegant approach, but my simple doc only needs a couple of text inserts to warrant going all the way, so for me I think the other method suggested is a bit easier (and quicker). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use PDF lib to write over a document, positionning is time consuming and boring. Dhek is useful for such task: https://github.com/cchantep/dhek/releases .

JSON mapping over PDF page/coordinates is defined, so that you can write with PDF API you prefer.