# How can I embed signature in the pdf file php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

In the application a user will upload a PDF file and then upload a personal signature created using a digital pen. How can I embed this signature in the pdf file?

I tried to use TCPDF but it seems that this library is used for creating new pdf files.

In my case I have my own PDF files uploaded by different users.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links.. Hope it may useful for you

```
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-write-to-an-existing-PDF-using-PHP-1073.php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299315/writing-drawing-over-a-pdf-template-document-in-php
```

To write / create a PDF file

```
http://www.fpdf.org/
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your support. I was doing the same thing but there is only one problem in this library. It takes the image of my own pdf and  place that image on a new pdf with signature. In my case I have few pdf with form elements and after signature the new pdf dosen't show form elements it shows only few white spaces.