# Go from html form to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, pdftk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filling PDF Forms with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php)

I have been looking and testing this for a couple days now and was wondering if anyone could point me in a different direction. I have a very long job application HTML form (jobapp.html) and a matching PDF (jobpdf.pdf) that have the same field names for all entries in both the HTML form and the PDF. I need to take the user data that is entered in the form and convert it to a PDF. This is what I have gathered so far but don't know if I am on track:

Is pdftk the only viable 3rd party app to accomplish this?

Using pdftk would i take the $_POST data collected for the user and generate a .fdf(user.fdf) then flatten the .fdf on the .pdf(job.pdf). So irregardless of where the fields are located on each document the information on the fdf would populate the pdf by field names?

Comment: There's http://tcpdf.org and http://fpdf.org as well. Plus http://www.pdflib.com/.

Comment: Looks like this is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php

Comment: If you're on a Linux host, [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Try [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php). It generates PDFs from HTML and CSS. It doesn't understand everything you might want, but for documents with relatively simple formatting it's good.