# Filling a PDF template with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file that functions as a template containing only textboxes. Is there any way I can fill the fields in via PHP? I have found examples of how to directly draw onto a PDF document when given x,y values, but I want to put values into my textboxes rather than doing that.

Comment: may be this post can help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourabh's link showed that this is impossible in Android, I'm reverting to using a HTML document with filler where the textboxs in the PDF were and replacing them in code.