# looking for regExp to return line between two strings that works with pdfgrep

Tags: regex, bash, multiline

Though I'm not totally new to regExp, they always give me headaches. Especially when not all forms of regular expressions can be used.

- The pattern has to work with pdfgrep as the information I'm looking for is inside a pdf Document.
- Obviously the document is multiline
- The resulting pattern will be used in a bash script if this does make any difference
- The keywords usually can be found more than once in the same file, while I need only the data between the first occurences of both keywords

The data looks like:

```
some text
some more text
even more information Date
                      02.Feb.2014
                      Customer
some more text
some more information
even more information Date
                      02.Feb.2014
                      Customer
some more text
some more information
...
```

The result of the command should be: 02.Feb.2014

I don't know which characters might be around this date (tabs, spaces ...) and I don't want to rely on them.

I tried

```
pdfgrep -h 'Date(.*?)Customer' *.pdf
```

which gave no result at all.

Next try was

```
pdfgrep -h '(?<=Date)(.*)(?=Customer)' *.pdf
```

which resulted in an error "Invalid preceding regular expression"

The best shot I can come up until now is

```
pdfgrep -h '(Date)[[:space:]]{,1}.{,100}[[:space:]](Customer){,1}' *.pdf
```

This returns all matching dates together with the first keyword. But I'd like a much more elegant way as regExp should be able to provide it.

I'd appreciate any useful hint ;)

Regards

Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint to use gs in combination with sed does the trick. Though I had to do some testing until it worked as desired.

The command used now is:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dFirstPate=1 -dLastPage=1 \
      -sOutputFile=- /path/to/my.pdf 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/Date/ {' \
      -e'n' -e's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 'p' -e '}'
```

Thanks to all contributors :)

Answer (score 0):

The only document you should ever read when using grep, awk, or sed regular expressions [is here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). It cleared a lot of stuff up for me.

```
sed -n -e '/even more information Date/ {' \
       -e '    n' \
       -e '    s/^[[:space:]]*//' \
       -e '    p' \
       -e '}'
```

UNIX regular expressions only look at *lines* in the file. you can't capture stuff in an RE across lines.

The above `sed` command looks for a line looking like `even more information Date`, looks at the next line, removes the white space, and prints that line (the one with `02.Feb.2014` on it). The `-n` option is used to suppress output (only print lines if "I tell you to", sed).

Comment: So I have to extract the whole PDF with pdfgrep and then I can pipe it through sed? Ok, I'll try this but it doesn't seem to be very efficient. I tried your code, which I had to adjust a bit, but it just finds 'Date' and nothing else. The command I used was: pdfgrep -h '.' *.pdf | sed -n -e '/Date/ {' -e 'n' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 'p' -e '}'

Comment: Honestly, if it was me, I'd convert the PDF to text and then use python or ruby to get what I needed. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451626/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-to-text-so-i-can-parse-that-text-with-php

Comment: XPDF won't work though. this server has no GUI and will never have.

Comment: It looks like the ghostscript extraction method is pretty good. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187250/pdf-text-extraction