# email a completed html form as a pdf from a webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I have created a html form and it stores the data using php/mysql. Now i want to have the user enter there email address and click submit and have a the filled out form sent to them via email.

Comment: then do it. you can use FPDF + phpMailer, as examples, if that's the question

Comment: You can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php

Comment: So what's the problem? Sanity checking email addresses? Generating PDFs? Sending email? Attaching files when sending and email? Attaching files when you don't have a real file by the output of a PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a HTML-email template with some PHP code to retrieve the info, then send to the user/client.

About the PDF thing, you can make PDF's via PHP using [PDF functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) (that use [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/)). Or look here too: http://devzone.zend.com/article/12492 If you'd like to use Zend framework.