# pdf editor that integrated with PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php)

Is there any pdf editor that integrated with PHP. The Case is When I open the link that contain pdf files,it is automatically open pdf editor.so that the user can directly edit pdf files and save it into the server. 
I already search about it but i haven't find any solution

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? I see no relation between PHP and PDF in this case.

Comment: I think (s)he wants a browser-based pdf editor allowing users to edit pdf files on a server, and the server uses php.

Comment: I created the system with php. when i click the link it is normally opened pdf files on web browser. i want to edited this pdf files directly and it is saved into the server. what kind of pdf editor that can be used?

Comment: @4mpi : yups,..seems like that.is there anybody knows?

Comment: Also, as an option, you could keep your content as HTML/XML and dynamically convert your content into PDF after editing.