# PDF Manipulation in Expression Engine

Tags: codeigniter, itext, expressionengine, pdf-manipulation

I am currently working on a project using the Expression Engine Framework, which as a c# developer is a little alien to me!

I am needing a pdf manipulation plugin for EE so that every PDF a client uploads has their profile's link appearing at the bottom (preferably clickable but not essential). I have had a look around but cannot find anything to help me. There is a watermarker in EE for images but not for PDFs which is annoying.

In C# we have Itextsharp which does the job perfectly - I wonder if I am going to have write a custom EE Extension to do the job for me.

Just wondered if anybody out there has ever had to do something similar and can point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to modify PDF's with PHP. See [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364/183254)

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/
http://www.fpdf.org/
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

These are just libraries, so load one into the application and use it in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if any of these yield a good result. Are you aware if it is possible to use the Zend Framework alongside EE? It seems like the library that does what I want to do the most.

Comment: If it were me I'd try first to get fpdi (the first link) working. Zend will be much more involved (see: http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2009/05/08/zend-and-expressionengine-working-together/)