# Change placeholder in PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am prototyping a quote system for our guys on the road.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is take details from a web form, which will be taken to populate a PDF template.

At the moment I reckon the best way is to create a PDF template with placeholders, e.g. [[clientname]], find that reference in the PDF then swap it with what we have in the form.

I am using codeigniter for the app out of experience with it for rapid prototyping. Does anyone know of a library or other such functionality that will allow me to easily modify a PDF document in this way?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *At the moment I reckon the best way is to create a PDF template with placeholders, e.g. [[clientname]]* - I would propose using AcroForm form fields instead. Filling forms is generally a fairly easy in many pdf libraries.

Answer (score 4):

PDFs are collection of objects that will be rendered by a page renderer; modifying the blocks by "replacing placeholders" *might* work but, on the other hand, it might not. For example if you write "[[zip_code]]" in a document, chances are that it will be kerned into three or more chunks, and the PDF (once made readable - it might not be) will *not* contain the ASCII sequence "[[zip_code]]" at all.

Your best bet is to use PDFLib or CPDF to generate a *blank pdf* from a template where you will store the coordinates of each text block. Actually you could just do that in a single PHP file [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-show-xy.php):

```
$tokens = array(
    'zip'     => array( 2500, 1730, ... ),
    'address' => array( 2600, 1234, ... ),
    ...
);
foreach ($tokens as $token => $info) {
    list ($x, $y /*, ..font... size...*/) = $info;
    PDF_show_XY ($pdf, $record[$token], $x, $y );
}
PDF_end_document($pdf);
```

Then when you have the page to "overlay" over your chosen background, you can do that with a tool such as `pdftk`:

```
pdftk foreground.pdf background background.pdf output merged.pdf
```

With the appropriate resolution unit (e.g. tenths of a mm), you can print the background and measure the positions of where you want the fields with an ordinary ruler.

The PDFs will be a bit bulkier than if you had generated them from scratch, but they *will* be print-perfect - the two layers will be "merged" on print, and won't otherwise interfere with each other.

Comment: Wow, thanks I hadn't considered this route at all. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ which will generate PDF's based on a web page. Should make things easy - just make the page look how you want, have the user fill in the relevant info, then generate the pdf.

As far as editing existing PDF's, see [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php).

http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/ and Zend look like the best options. However, Zend seems to be difficult to work with given your constraints. Might be worth at least testing dompdf if budget is a concern.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Not looking for HTML to PDF as we already have a stylised PDF template in use. Rather than alter this document manually each time we simply want placeholders in the PDF that will be replaced with variables held in/automated responses formulated in PHP.