# PDF Book Compiler/Maker Drupal Website

Tags: php, wordpress, compiler-construction, module, drupal-7

I came through a website here: http://perkinswill.com/mybook where visitors to the site can select specific project pages to add to a “book”, which they can download as a PDF.

For example, http://perkinswill.com/type/civic-cultural, you can add any project in your book. In addition, you can customize the book title when send to your email address.

I want to know how this is achieved. What programming is used here? Any Drupal module? Can Wordpress achieve the same functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is built using php.
You can know from url if you append [index.php](http://perkinswill.com/mybook/index.php) page opens.
If you want to reconfirm you should evaluate header sent by server.

If you want to edit PDF file your self there are many 3rd party libraries available to edit PDF files using php. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php) for more information on editing PDF

Comment: thank you for the helpful info! I noticed that the PDF that website generates is interactive. For example, when you click on a project image on the PDF it leads you to the project page on the website. I wondered if the PDF are layout and programmed by PHP or they are designed beforehand?

Comment: It all depends on your document if you are generating a report the pdf may be completely generated by php, if you want to modify a section they are used as a template.