# cakephp pdf form update

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf

I am using cakephp 2.5 and I have a template certificate pdf with two form fields for the name and the course.

Beside a list of users who have completed the course I have a download button where the certificate can be downloaded with the users name and the course they have completed.

I have looked at Cakepdf but it seems that the default template has to be in html. Is there another way to just update the fields in a pdf with something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF Editing in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php)

Comment: thanks, I am looking for something more compatible with cakephp. Cakepdf works with third party libraries so maybe someone got it to update a pdf instead of creating a new one

Comment: I doubt that, CakePDF is primarily designed for HTML to PDF conversion, also questions seeking for software are genereally not suited for SO, they will most likely be closed one way or another. You're probably better off asking such question on IRC or the Google group.