# PHP function to search for text inside online pdf, replace it & save modified pdf on the server

Tags: php, pdf

Is there a way in PHP that can open remote PDF file, searching for specific text, replace it with new one & save the modified PDF file on the server?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of tools or just one of them. Depends on how complex the file is and how much noise either of these generates.

1. [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) - converts HTML to PDF.
2. [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) - creates PDF files.
3. [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) - uses already existing PDF files.

My personal recommendation would be to go for `FPDI`.

Comment: I try FPDI, but the pdf file I wanna use is 'extract deny' protection

Comment: Not sure if FPDI can deal with that, but there seems to be a [tool that can](https://superuser.com/a/924794/203115).

Answer (score 0):

After many days of research, there is no plugin can extract pdf data from 'extraction protected' PDF.