# Core PHP, Hide some text from the PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I need to remove some area from my pdf file. First I am uploading a PDF file using core PHP code, then I want to remove or add white space by providing `x`, `y` coordinate points.

I need help to do this using PHP code?

Comment: Content in PDF files is usually contained in layers and objects. For example, you can add a white box at X,Y coordinates, but the content beneath will still remain (even though it may not be visible). If you need to properly sanitise a section of a PDF document, then you will need to actually remove/edit existing layers.

Comment: Adding white box is fine for me, but is there any PHP lib available to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php)