# Open PDF with PHP and change Placeholder

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, placeholder

I'll explain my problem: I have a PDF that is generated using ADOBE READER DC PRO and, on each page, there is a signature field (for digital signature) that will be signed later by the user. My problem is that I should be able to fill the PDF with data by opening it and replacing certain placeholders.
I've checked everything online but haven't found a suitable solution: do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much for helping.

[digital sign example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pRN7.png)
[placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu3cs.png)

Comment: There are some pdf parsers out there, like: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
or http://www.fpdf.org/. 
Very identical question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php

Comment: *"fill the PDF with data by opening it and replacing certain placeholders"* - depending on how those place holders are created this can be more or less difficult. It is definitively a sign of a bad software design. You might want to ask your employer / project lead / client if one could use form fields instead of those placeholders.